# Fulltext search hit-highlighting in combination with a SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, hit-highlighting

I want to hightlight the search word (hits) in the search results. I use the fulltext search with e.g. `where contains(html, 'formsof(INFLECTIONAL, search word)')`.

How I get the right hits from the SQL server to highlight them in the frontend?

I could not find an optimal solution for me. I have already tested the following things:

[ThinkHighlight for SQL Server](https://www.interactivethoughts.com/products/thinkhighlight/)

[Script from Mike Kramar](http://mkramar.blogspot.com/2011/05/hit-highlight-for-sqlserver-full-text_5118.html)

Is there a good solution (script, library) for highlighting search hits? Also like a commercial solution.

Comment: What was you experience with ThinkHighlight?